# _True/False test:_ Let $A\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ such that $A^2=A.$ Then $\text{rank}A=\text{trace}A.$

Tags: linear-algebra

*True/False test:* Let $A\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ such that $A^2=A.$ Then $\text{rank}A=\text{trace}A.$

*My attempt:*

$A$ satisfies $x^2-x$ i.e. $x(x-1).$ So $0,1$ are the only possible eigenvalues of $A.$ Also

$m_A|x(x-1)\\\implies x \text{ and } x-1\text{ are the only possible irreducible factors of } m_A\\\implies x \text{ and } x-1\text{ are the only possible irreducible factors of } \chi_A\\\implies \chi_A(x)=x^{n-i}(x-1)^{i}\text{ where }0\le i\le n\\\implies\text{eigenvalues of }A=0~(\text{n-i fold}),1~(\text{i fold})\\\implies\text{rank}A=i$

Again $\chi_A(x)=x^{n-i}(x-1)^{i}=x^{n-i}(x^i-ix^{i-1}+...)\\\implies\text{trace}A=(-1)^{n-1}\times\text{coefficient of }x^{n-1}=(-1)^{n-1}(-i)=(-1)^n i$

Comment: Are these questions from a test in progress?

Comment: yes${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Then why are you asking for help instead of solving the problems yourself?

Comment: These're not assignment problems. It appeared in previous years questions. I'm asking only those which I couldn't able to solve. I solved 18 out of 22.

Comment: Tests from last year are not in progress.  You may find your questions deleted because of this misunderstanding.

Comment: Also I'm trying to put all my thoughts and attempts with each problem. The previous problem I posted was just for verification of my answer.

Comment: sorry I got it wrong.

Comment: @Sriti thik thak e mone hochhey. $(-1)^n=1$ hobe to as its even any how?

Comment: @TaxiDriver even kno?

Comment: $A$ is diagonalisable since $X^2 - X$ is a polynomial with simple roots such that $(X^2 - X)(A) = 0$. What is the diagonal form of $A$ ?

Comment: @Plop Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 2):

*This is a CW answer intended to push this question off of the unanswered queue.*

---

Plop has commented with a good hint:

> A is diagonalisable since $X^2−X$ is a polynomial with simple roots such that $(X^2−X)(A)=0$. What is the diagonal form of $A$ ?